# Plot ssr-based granger causality: pulling values from list within a dictionary within a dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, statistics, graphing

I'm relatively new to coding with Python, and I'm working on a project involving signal analysis. I have several data sets, but for simplicity I will ask this question using only two of them.

First, information about the data:

- Two time series data sets
- Sampling rate 1x/day
- 11 values of data missing in an 826 column set, lack of functionality in python to handle nan's meant I truncated at the 677th lag, one before the first missing value.
- Both pass the augmented dickey fuller test, IE they are stationary. This is suspicious to me, but for now I'll go with it.
- I normalized the data using boxcox.

## I am trying to test if aos causes aucs.

The relevant lines of code are (as of now):

```py
mydict = statsmodels.tsa.stattools.grangercausalitytests(zip(aucs[1:677],aos[1:677]), maxlag=100, addconst=True, verbose=True)
pp.pprint(mydict)
```

"Verbose" mode in the function call produces very nice output, for example, for the 79th lag:

```
Granger Causality
number of lags (no zero) 79
ssr based F test:         F=1.0481  , p=0.3772  , df_denom=438, df_num=79
ssr based chi2 test:   chi2=112.8566, p=0.0075  , df=79
likelihood ratio test: chi2=103.3680, p=0.0343  , df=79
parameter F test:         F=1.0481  , p=0.3772  , df_denom=438, df_num=79
```

From my research, the ssr-based F test is the "standard" granger causality test, and therefore the one I want to use for my project.

I want to do two things: (1) print each of these to a file, (2) graph the ssr based F distribution and associated p-values/confidence bounds.

However, for the first problem, the "verbose" mode code is built into the actual function (i.e. I pass my entire data set to that function). It iteratively prints the output as it performs calculations, and then returns the entire dictionary structure at once, separately. Thus, I cannot "print" the output to a file (it's within the function), and I cannot print the dictionary (it's several levels deep).

Here is the structure of a two lags, using pretty printer, which I get from the actual output:

```
{ 1: ( { 'lrtest': (3.4447802797894838, 0.063451857791777685, 1),
         'params_ftest': (3.438235992254306, 0.064141599476182851, 672.0, 1),
         'ssr_chi2test': (3.4535852600768981, 0.063114725408777453, 1),
         'ssr_ftest': (3.4382359922543344, 0.06414159947617562, 672.0, 1)},
       [ <statsmodels.regression.linear_model.RegressionResultsWrapper object at 0x116ccd210>,
         <statsmodels.regression.linear_model.RegressionResultsWrapper object at 0x116cc9d90>,
         array([[ 0.,  1.,  0.]])]),
  2: ( { 'lrtest': (2.849736097306959, 0.24054020071776955, 2),
         'params_ftest': (1.4172919220343254, 0.24309625306924146, 669.0, 2),
         'ssr_chi2test': (2.8557690745918363, 0.23981570719685263, 2),
         'ssr_ftest': (1.4172919220340792, 0.24309625306930535, 669.0, 2)},
       [ <statsmodels.regression.linear_model.RegressionResultsWrapper object at 0x116cc9590>,
         <statsmodels.regression.linear_model.RegressionResultsWrapper object at 0x116cc9490>,
         array([[ 0.,  0.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.,  0.]])]),
```

As you can see, this is rather messy. I realize I need to do several for loops (i.e. for `x in mydict`, `for y in mydict[x]`, etc.), but there are so many different levels/types of data getting spit out that I'm lost as to exactly how to loop. I keep getting errors involving iteration (i.e. can't loop over this data type because this isn't iterable, etc.). I want to print these values to a text file such that they look the same as they do in the "verbose" mode output. Then, I want to pull the individual column values and create an array (F-value for each lag), and plot it.

I apologize if this is a simple question, and any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You don't need to print them to a text file, you can put the results into an array for plotting. Do you want the results for all lags or only maxlags?

Answer (score 0):

When you set `maxlags=2` then lags of 1 and 2 are performed. The lags and the results are the first key:value pair in the returned dict. Then the dict of test results is the first element of the value tuple, and the F-score is the first tuple element of the key-value pair for `ssr_ftest`.  So to get that value for lag 2 you would use

```
fscore = mydict[2][0]['ssr_ftest'][0]
```